# Where in the Star Wars original trilogy does this translucent green orb in a circular dish appear?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification

This is a Star Wars poster that I own:

[image: SW OT Poster]

It's a collage of different scenes, characters and other elements from the Original Trilogy.

Near the top is this orb, apparently floating above a hole in a flat circular container:

[image]

It doesn't resemble any element of Star Wars that I know of, so I was hoping someone could tell me what it is. I know it's not [the Orb of Peace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Globe_of_Peace/Canon), as the poster only shows things from the Original Trilogy. It looks vaguely like part of the Death Star, but not like any part I recognize.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

[image]That's the hologram of the forest moon of Endor from Return of the Jedi.  I'm sure if you look closely, you'll see a hologram of the second death star orbiting it.

Comment: Definitely readable. I give it a 7/10

Answer (score 32):

## It's Endor

Well, technically speaking:

> the Forest Moon of Endor and the Sanctuary Moon

([Source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Endor))

Looking at this image below from *Return of the Jedi*, you'll see the projection of the Death Star II with shielding with Endor being the green planet right next to it

[image]

Comment: Is the moon called endor, or is the planet it orbits endor?  I was always confused about it.

Comment: @CBredlow It's a moon called Endor, orbiting a planet called Endor, in the Endor system.

Comment: @RogueJedi in the Endor quadrant, in the Endor Galaxy?

Comment: @CBredlow also the site of an elite battle school, as seen in _Endor's game_.

Comment: @terdon I think it is about time we Endor this pun... :)

Comment: @Erik this is just getting [teekious](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Teek_%28species%29)

Comment: @Erik - I Endor(se) this policy

Comment: How much more of this must we Endore?

Comment: @MrLister: Of this, there will be no End... or?

Comment: @terdon also home of the fabled _Ent-Orc_, known from the _Bride of Saruman_ direct-to-DVD movie

Comment: Or the founder of one of the Houses in Harry Potter. His first name was Gryff.

Comment: end[o]rland approves!

Comment: Endore this talk about Endor, you must.

Comment: Its sister moon is Encore, where one's standing in society is based on one's endorance for the endorless and endoring Endor puns. Endorians *really* dislike talking with Encorians -- just imagine what they must endor!

Comment: This whole thread is so endorable.

Comment: Endor orbits Endor in Endor - is it just me or does it sound to anyone else like somebody's originality quota was exhausted. Q:"Hey, George - what do we call the moon?" A:"Endor" Q:"And what planet does it orbit?" A:"Endor!" Q:"And...what system is this in?" A:"Endor!!!" Q:"Yeeeeah. George, are you...OK..?" A:"Endor! Endor!! Endor!!! Jedi! Sith! SITH-EYE!! Death Star! Robots! Ro! Bots! Zot! Zam! BOOOM!!! Giggle-giggle-giggle-giggle-giggle-giggle-giggle!!!!!" Q:"OK, people, that's a wrap for today. And...somebody get a towel. George is drooling again..."

Comment: By the way, for people still interested, the webcomic [Darths and Droids](http://darthsanddroids.net/episodes/1309.html) has now caught up.

Comment: Endor. http://cdn.movieweb.com/img.news.tops/NEm5OcdSzEkUpv_2_b.jpg